# R time series object with two time dimensions

Tags: datetime, r

When you study time series forecast you most often have to deal with two times: the time you issue your forecast and the time you make your forecast for. These two times are not regularly sampled in general.

What R object do you suggest to deal with these two times ? 
please indicate advantages and drawback.
If no object exist, how should I use existing S4 object to create what I need?

Thanks in advance for sharing your experience in R with this type of data

Answer (score 1):

The [zoo package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) is useful for dealing with irregularly sampled time series.

Whether you use the issue time or the forecast time seems to <del>be a meterological problem</del> depend on what you're asking rather than an `R` problem; if you want a better answer, you'll have to provide more detail.

See the [Rosetta code page on classes](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Classes#R) for a brief intro to S4.  Again, better answers require more detail.

(edited to remove assumption about what you were forecasting)

Comment: Thanks Richie Cotton, Yes, I also think using Zoo xts object is a good starting point. 
Richie Cotton said
''seems to be a meterological problem rather than an R problem''
Meteorological problem is a good example but surely not the only one. In energy planning, financial product, you find this type of problem with two time dimensions.